# Invalid or corrupt jar file when trying to start selenium server from intelliJ

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to start my selenium server from intelliJ and it is saying the file is corrupt.

I use intelliJ to run my protractor tests, and when I starts the selenium server from the intelliJ terminal before I run them. For whatever reason it is saying my jar file for selenium-server-standalone is coming back as corrupt. Is there a way to fix this and, if not, is there a way to delete and then reinstall selenium server?

> C:\Users\pheonix.jones\IdeaProjects\attensity-q-protractor>webdriver-manager
>   start [11:39:09] I/start - java
>   -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\pheonix.jones\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.46.exe
>   -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\pheonix.jones\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
>   tractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.24.0.exe
>   -jar C:\Users\pheonix.jones\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip.jar
>   -port 4444 [11:39:09] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 2748 Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile
>   C:\Users\pheonix.jones\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip.jar
>   [11:39:09] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1

As you can see, it is just exiting after it comes back as corrupt. I haven't had issues with this before. I did try to update the webdriver.

Comment: @P Jones: what is your server version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an open defect in the webdriver-manager project for this issue: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/370

As a temporary workaround you can use the directConnect attribute in your protractor config.

Answer (score 45):

I found a workaround, which may or may not be acceptable. You can force webdriver-manager to use an older version of the selenium-standalone package. This avoids whatever the problem is with `4.0.0-alpha-1`.

```
$ webdriver-manager clean
$ webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0
$ webdriver-manager start --versions.standalone=3.8.0
…
[14:19:55] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 63863
14:19:55.379 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.8.0', revision: '924c4067df'
14:19:55.380 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2019-04-24 14:19:55.483:INFO::main: Logging initialized @390ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
```

Comment: I followed your instructions, but I get a ```Selenium Standalone server encountered an error: Error: spawn java ENOENT
 ```

Answer (score 3):

There is issue with 4.0.0-alpha-1 , after deleting files you can install some older versions that will work. If you will just update wevdriver manager by using **webdriver-manager update** then it will not work for you but you need to use something like " **webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone="some older version**"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Protractor, you can try a `webdriver-manager update`

You should be starting the server like this - `webdriver-manager start`

I believe Protractor's webdriver-manager already contains the selenium standalone server.

Or you can just add this line in your conf file, and you will no longer need to manually start anything before running a Protractor spec file `directConnect: true`

Comment: Running `webdriver-manager update` just downloads the same file again (`selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip.jar`) and you get the same error as in the original post.